# Determining cause of CPU spike in azure

Tags: azure, cpu

I am relatively new to Azure. I have a website that has been running for a couple of months with not too much traffic...when users are on the system, the various dashboard monitors go up and then flat line the rest of the time. This week, the CPU time when way up when there were no requests and data going in or out of the site. Is there a  way to determine the cause of this CPU activity when the site is not active?  It doesn't make sense to me that I should have CPU activity being assigned to my site when there is to site activity.

Comment: Too sad nobody has answered this. I have the same question: there are CPU spikes and I don't know what is causing them

Answer (score 1):

If your website has significant processing at application start, it is possible your VM got rebooted or your app pool recycled and your onstart handler got executed again (which would cause CPU to spike without any request). 
You can analyze this by adding application logs to your Application_Start event (but after initializing trace). There is another comment detailing how to enable logging, but you can also consult [this link](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-enable-diagnostic-log/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to collect data to understand what's going on.  So first thing I would say is:
1. Go to Azure management portal -> your website (assuming you are using Azure websites) -> dashboard -> operation logs.  Try to see whether there is any suspicious activity going on.

1. download the logs for your site using any ftp client and analyze what's happening.  If there is not much data, I would suggest adding more logging in your application to see what is happening or which module is spinning.

Comment: how can you determine if something is suspicious? I've seen the logs and they are a series of lines of the form "HTTP-GET /Controller/Action?parameters". From that how can you tell what caused the CPU spike?

Comment: Here are some more details on how you can add additional logging in your application to see where time is spent. http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio/#apptracelogs

Answer (score 0):

A great way to detect CPU spikes and even determine slow running areas of your application is to use a profiler like [New Relic](http://newrelic.com/azure). It's a free add on for Azure that collects data and provides you with a dashboard of data. You might find it useful to determine the exact cause of the CPU spike.

We regularly use it to monitor the performance of our applications. I would recommend it.